# Node js Empty object when executing a function from a required file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

so i have this news api js file i can run and execute the api and see a full result when consoling

```js
const NewsAPI = require('newsapi');
const newsapi = new NewsAPI('2a59HIDDEN1bd60');



  newsapi.v2.sources({
    category: 'technology',
    language: 'en',
    country: 'us'
  }).then( response => {
  console.log(response)
    return response
  });
```

but when i require the above code in another file its coming as empty object

```js
const passport = require("passport");
const newsapiapi = require("../services/newsApi");

module.exports = (app) => {


  app.get(
    "/auth/google",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
      scope: ["profile", "email"],
    })
  );

  app.get("/auth/google/callback", passport.authenticate("google"));
  app.get('/api/current_user',(req,res)=>{
      res.send(req.user);
  })
  app.get('/api/newsapi',(req,res)=>{
    var resp =  newsapiapi
    console.log("-----------",resp)
    
    res.send("hello")

})
};
```

In other words the object is empty when executing under  app.get('/api/newsapi') but i get the data with no issue on the first code where the api lies

Comment: The file at the top is supposed to be the content of `../services/newsApi.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you haven't exported anything from the api file.
Try this

```
module.exports = newsapi.v2.sources({
    category: 'technology',
    language: 'en',
    country: 'us'
  }).then( response => {
  console.log(response)
    return response
  });
```

This would export the function promise and then you can consume it by resolving it in the main file. Like

```
app.get('/api/newsapi', async (req,res)=>{
    var resp = await newsapiapi()
    console.log("-----------",resp)

    res.send("hello")

})
```

Or if you don't want to use async-await, you can use promise chaining like

```
app.get('/api/newsapi',(req,res)=>{
    var resp =  newsapiapi().then(resp => {
    console.log("-----------",resp) 
    res.send("hello")
   })

})
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are not exporting anything from the above file. add module.exports.

```
module.exports = newsapi.v2.sources({
        category: 'technology',
        language: 'en',
        country: 'us'
      }).then( response => {
      console.log(response)
        return response
      });
```